# Define abstract read-write property to force getter and setter implementation

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, abstract

### Docs

Python docs (version 3.8):

> The above example defines a read-only property; you can also define a read-write abstract property by appropriately marking one or more of the underlying methods as abstract:

```
class C(ABC):
    @property
    def x(self):
        ...

    @x.setter
    @abstractmethod
    def x(self, val):
        ...
```

> If only some components are abstract, only those components need to be updated to create a concrete property in a subclass:

### My Code

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
class C(ABC):
    @property
    def x(self):
        ...

    @x.setter
    @abstractmethod
    def x(self, val):
        ...

class D(C):
    @property
    def x(self):
        pass

d = D()
```

**Expected behaviour**: Fails to instantiate because there are undefined abstract methods

**Actual behaviour**: Instantiates without error

### Question

Why doesn't this fail to instantiate? How do I write this so it does fail to instantiate if no setter is implemented in the derived class. The docs seems to indicate that this should be a covered use-case for `abstractmethod`. The docs also provide an example where both the getter and the setter are abstract methods which is what I'm aiming for.

Reference:
https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/abc.html#abc.abstractproperty

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally the issue is that the getter and the setter are just part of the same single class attribute. Within in the `@property` `x` you've got a `fget`, `fset`, and `fdel` which make up the getter, setter, and deleter (not necessarily all set). Those could be abstract and prevent the init, or just not exist.

In your `class D` you make a new `@property` which entirely overrides the parent `@property` so there is no longer any abstract setter to prevent initing the class.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
class C(ABC):
    @property
    def x(self):
        pass

    @x.setter
    @abstractmethod
    def x(self, val):
        pass

class D(C):
    @property
    def x(self):
        pass

def examine_property(p):
    print('get', p.fget, getattr(p.fget, '__isabstractmethod__', False) if p.fget is not None else None)
    print('set', p.fset, getattr(p.fset, '__isabstractmethod__', False) if p.fset is not None else None)
    print('del', p.fdel, getattr(p.fdel, '__isabstractmethod__', False) if p.fdel is not None else None)

print("C.x:")
examine_property(C.x)
print("D.x:")
examine_property(D.x)
```

Output:

```
C.x:
get <function C.x at 0x101ac4550> False
set <function C.x at 0x101ac45e0> True
del None None
D.x:
get <function D.x at 0x101ac4670> False
set None None
del None None
```

So, if you want to override the getter, you need to be very specific about it using `@C.x.getter`:

```
class D(C):
    @C.x.getter
    def x(self):
        print("non-abstract getter")
```

Output:

```
C.x:
get <function C.x at 0x1022fb550> False
set <function C.x at 0x1022fb5e0> True
del None None
D.x:
get <function D.x at 0x1022fb670> False
set <function C.x at 0x1022fb5e0> True
del None None
```

This way you don't override the whole `property`, just the specific function of it.

I wouldn't go mixing making new `properties` and overriding parents, I saw this finicky behaviour in my testing:

```
class D(C):
    @property
    def x(self):
        pass
    @C.x.setter
    def x(self, val):
        pass
print("D.x:")
examine_property(D.x)
```

Output:

```
D.x:
get <function C.x at 0x10cdd74c0> False
set <function D.x at 0x10cdd7670> False
del None None
# Our new override property is gone
```

Reordered class definition:

```
class D(C):
    @C.x.setter
    def x(self, val):
        pass
    @property
    def x(self):
        pass
```

Output:

```
D.x:
get <function D.x at 0x105048670> False
set None None
del None None
# We entirely lost the `setter`
```